# jquery-ui: trigger the select of an selectable ol-li-list

Tags: jquery-ui, triggers

How can I trigger the select-event inside some jquery code?

**edit:**
I'm using jquery-ui selectable.
The selectable items are <"li"> inside an <"ol"> list.
(documentation: http://jqueryui.com/demos/selectable/)

I cant trigger it by "click" nor "selecting" nor "select" ...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3140017/jquery-ui-how-to-programatically-select-selectables/4863890#4863890 was working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$('#elem_id').select();
```

http://docs.jquery.com/Events/select

Comment: this would have helped if I wouldn't have asked my question wrong.. sorry

see the edit

Answer (score 0):

Ok, now that you've edited, I'll try this one as well:

This isn't an *exact* replica of a select, but depending on your situation, could do what you need.

```
var desired_option_index = 1;
$('ol#myOptions li').eq(desired_option_index).addClass('ui-selected');
```

If you have callback functions that are important, you could call those explicitly right afterward, or before, depending on the event.

Comment: this adds only the css-class, but doesnt trigger the actual click

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#selectable2").selectable({
 filter: "div",
 selecting: function(ev, ui) {
 $(ui.selecting).text('selecting');
 },
 selected: function(ev, ui) {
 $(ui.selected).text('selected');
 },
 unselecting: function(ev, ui) {
 $(ui.unselecting).text('unselecting');
 },
 unselected: function(ev, ui) {
 $(ui.unselected).text('unselected');
 }
 });
```

[DEMO](http://interface.eyecon.ro/demos/select.htm)