# Trigger jQuery UI events: ui-selectable

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-ui-selectable

### EDIT:

the jQuery UI selectable widget has a callback built into it, `stop`, I need to know how to trigger this event programmatically.

---

**(this was poorly worded)**
I've attached an event listener to the jQuery UI [**Selectable Widget**](http://jqueryui.com/demos/selectable/#event-selected).  How can I programmatically trigger the `stop` event?

---

### Ex Selectable:

```
$("table").selectable({
  filter: "tr",
  stop: function(){
    //do stuff
  }
});

// Various attempts at triggering the stop event
// one
$("table .ui-selected").click();

// two
$("table .ui-selected").select();

// three
$("table .ui-selected").trigger("click");

// shot in the dark 1
$("table").selectable('widget').trigger('stop');

// Shot in the dark 2
$("table").trigger('stop');

// really long shot in the dark
$("table").selectable('widget').call('stop');
```

### Further Attempts

```
// selectablestop event

$("#table").selectable('widget').trigger('selectablestop');

$("#table .ui-selected").trigger('selectablestop');
```

Comment: i'm trying to trigger the jquery ui selection event.  I have this widget in some tabs and I need to be able to re-trigger the selection event upon showing the tab.

Comment: sorry, made the question a bit more clear.

Comment: why dont u use all the callbacks that come with the plugin?

Comment: @ neal - I am. I am asking how to programmatically trigger this callback

Comment: have you tried "selectablestop"?

Comment: I found this similar question - but it's meant for the jQuery ui Slider widget... not sure how a comparable solution would work for the selectable widget.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want to trigger the event outside of the control you can simply call `.trigger()`.  This assumes you are using the `.bind()` and not the anonymous `stop:function()` in options.

```
$("#selectable").selectable({});
$("#selectable").bind("selectablestop", function(event) {
    $("body").append("<h1>did selectablestop</h1>");
});
$(":button").click(function() {
    $('#selectable').trigger('selectablestop');
});
```

**Code example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/zCh5p/1/).**

**Edit**

Another way would be to retrieve the `stop:` option value (which would be the function)

```
var s = $('#selectable').selectable( "option" , "stop"); 
s(); //call the function.
```

**Code example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/zCh5p/2/).**

Comment: right, as shown in my example i'm using the stop callback.  How do i trigger this event programatically?  EX: `$( '.selector' ).trigger('selectablestop');`

Comment: hmmm.  it CAN be done! thx much must be something wrong w/ my code.

Answer (score 4):

I ended up doing this, found at [How to programmatically select selectables with jQuery UI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3140017/jquery-ui-how-to-programatically-select-selectables)

```
 $('#selectable').data("selectable")._mouseStop(null);
```

This will trigger the mouse stop event and execute the binded stop function on the selectable. If there's a way to trigger the stop in a more elegant way, I would love to see.

Comment: Hope this help new questions: For later versions of the jQuery UI library, we should use .data("ui-selectable") instead of .data("selectable")