# jquery ui selectable: manually/programmatically selecting child

Tags: jquery-ui, select

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to programmatically select selectables with jQuery UI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3140017/how-to-programmatically-select-selectables-with-jquery-ui)

Does anyone know how to manually or programmatically select a child item of a jQuery UI selectable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't exclusive to a selectable object, but if you just want to get the html node, you can use the `:nth-child()` selector found [here](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/).

```
$(".selector li:nth-child(2)")
```

Depending on what you need to do with this child, this may work for you.

EDIT

I think I missed your intended meaning of 'select'.  I don't immediately see an easy way to use the API to select an item, but you could always just add the class `ui-selected` to a child item and the css should take care of the rest.  This probably won't trigger API events, however.

Or, you could just do

```
$(".selector li:nth-child(2)").click();
```

to select with a fake mouse click.

Comment: Thanks for response. Adding the class ui-selected is a start. Even though events do not fire, I still have enough context to decide what needs to be done.  I tried calling click on my selector which looks like this  $('#stop_1111') but did not get desired effect.

Answer (score 0):

From my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3140017/how-to-programmatically-select-selectables-with-jquery-ui)...

http://jsfiddle.net/XYJEN/1/

```
function SelectSelectableElements (selectableContainer, elementsToSelect)
{
    // add unselecting class to all elements in the styleboard canvas except the ones to select
    $(".ui-selected", selectableContainer).not(elementsToSelect).removeClass("ui-selected").addClass("ui-unselecting");

    // add ui-selecting class to the elements to select
    $(elementsToSelect).not(".ui-selected").addClass("ui-selecting");

    // trigger the mouse stop event (this will select all .ui-selecting elements, and deselect all .ui-unselecting elements)
    selectableContainer.data("selectable")._mouseStop(null);
}
```