# Why is data("selectable") returning "undefined"?

Tags: jquery, selectable

I followed the following question to implement "select all" functionality: 
[How to programmatically select selectables with jQuery UI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3140017/how-to-programmatically-select-selectables-with-jquery-ui)

The select all button works perfectly up to the point of the ._mouseStop command, and then it just spits out the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method '_mouseStop' of undefined
```

Here is the relevant part of the code:

Step 1: There are four lists on this page, and all four of them are using the selectable plugin

```
//Make all four lists selectable
$("#selectNewTweets").selectable();
$("#selectApprovedTweets").selectable();
$("#selectDeclinedTweets").selectable();
$("#selectUndecidedTweets").selectable();
```

Step 2: Mass-register all the "Select All" buttons (one for each list)

```
//click a "Select All" button
$("[id^=btnSelectAll]").click(function(e){
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var list = id.substring(
        "btnSelectAll".length,
        id.length);
    //select all elements in target list
    $("#select"+list+"Tweets > li").each(function(index){
        $(this).removeClass('ui-selected');
        $(this).addClass("ui-selecting");
    });

    $("#select"+list+"Tweets").data("selectable")._mouseStop(null);
});
```

When I click any of the "Select All" buttons, the elements inside all get the "ui-selecting" class, so the .each() statement is working perfectly. However, once it reaches the ._mouseStop() line, it throws the exception I mentioned above.

Any ideas what's causing the exception?

Answer (score 3):

If you notice [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3140017/how-to-programmatically-select-selectables-with-jquery-ui#comment21791674_9421157) for the selected answer to the StackOverflow question you reference, it says that for later versions of the jQuery UI library, you should use `.data("ui-selectable")` instead of `.data("selectable")`. Hopefully that is the reason for the error you are getting because I see nothing else wrong with your code.